# Nice Kotlin way create custom initializer for Singelton?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing an Android app using the [RoomDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase) component. Is there a way to let AppDatabase be an object and telling it during instantiation to use

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                ).build()
```

Here is the full example:

```
@Database(
    entities = arrayOf(AppInfo::class),
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun applicationInfoDao(): ApplicationInfoDao

    companion object {

        private const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "ApplicationInfoDB"
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        //-- get the singleton instance of the database
        fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                )
                    .build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think  you should use dependency injection and inject `AppDatabase.getInstance(context)` as an object.